# What algorithm to use for a word search using a hash table?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, hashtable

This is an assignment.

I have a hash table (array of linked lists) that contains a bunch of words from an English dictionary.

I also have a 2d array of letters of up to 100 x 100, but I'll just show 3x3 for now:

```
[a][b][c]
[g][a][c]
[b][t][a]
```

Like any word search, words can be lined up horizontally, vertically, diagonally, and backwards.

I only showed a small grid here, but if I had a bigger grid, there'd be bigger words too.

How would I find the words in the array? It looks like I'd only need "bat" and "cab" here. Imagine we had a bigger grid and the words could go up to 20 letters. This is all I can come up with:

1. start somewhere on the grid
2. check for a 2 letter word
3. check in all 8 directions
4. throw whatever you found into the hash table to check for a match
5. repeat step 2 except for 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 letter words
6. go back to step 1, move over a place on the grid and repeat

Seems like a really silly way of doing it.

Comment: A hash table isn't a good fit for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Hash-table**

The simplest (although not particularly efficient) approach is simple recursion.

For each cell, recursively look around, keeping track of the current word and, at each step, checking whether the current word is contained in the hash table.

```
set up hash table with all words

for each cell c
  findWords(c, c.value)

findWords(cell c, string current)
  if current.length > longestWord
    return
  if hashTable.contains(current)
    output current
  for each neighbour n of c
    findWords(n, current + c.value)
```

Now, to make this more efficient, we can essentially simulate a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

We'll put all prefixes of every word into the hash table, so for `"johnny"`, you'd have `"j"`, `"jo"`, `"joh"`, `"john"`, `"johnn"` and `"johnny"` in the hash table.

We can just have a flag in the hash table to indicate whether or not the given entry is a valid word. So, for the above, only `"johnny"` would have this flag.

```
set up hash table with all words, but also all prefixes of words

for each cell c
  findWords(c, c.value)

findWords(cell c, string current)
  if hashTable.contains(current)
    if isValidWord(current)
      output current
    for each neighbour n of c
      findWords(n, current + c.value)
```

### **Trie**

A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) seems like a better data structure for this problem.

First, construct the trie with all the words. Then, for each position on the grid, check whether there's an edge from the root for its value. If there is, recursively check each of it's neighbours, checking whether there's an edge for that value, and checking it's neighbours, and so on.

The pseudo-code is something like this:

```
set up trie with all words

for each cell c
  if root.hasChild(c.value)
    findWords(root.getChild(c.value), c)

findWords(node n, cell c)
  if n.isValidWord
    output n.getWord
  for each neighbour ne of c
    if n.hasChild(ne.value)
      findWords(n.getChild(ne.value), ne)
```

Comment: I was just thinking a extended radix trie would probably play this out much better than a hash table, probably as you were writing this up.

Comment: i added that this was for an assignment, so unfortunately i must use a hash table. all i can come up with is just a bunch of nested for loops.